# Tranforming 3D Matrices with translate, rotate, and scale in GLM

Tags: c++, matrix, glm-math

In the program I'm developing using Vulkan, I have the camera orbiting an object, where the object model (transformation) matrix is initialized like so:

```
glm::mat4 translate {glm::translate(glm::mat4{1.0}, object.position)};
    
glm::mat4 rotate {glm::rotate(translate, object.rotation, glm::vec3{0.0f, 1.f, 0.f})};

glm::mat4 model {glm::scale(rotate, glm::vec3{1.f, 1.f, 1.f})};

object.model = model;
```

EDIT: Y-Axis Rotation Only

Using the `glm::rotate` code below, I can change the rotation of the object through mouse motion events that calculate the changes in rotation and applying them to the matrix. There are no problems up to this point.

```
object.model = glm::rotate(
    object.model,
    deltaYRotation,
    glm::vec3{0.f, 1.f, 0.f});
```

However, when I try to apply translations to the model matrix using the code below, other than when the rotation = 0.f, the translation messes up completely (Every frame, changes in rotation are applied before changes in translation).

```
object.model = glm::translate(
    object.model,
    glm::vec3{velocity.x, 0.f, velocity.z});
```

But when I use the first set of code shown previously (that was used to initialize the matrix) to recreate the entire model transformation matrix, the translation applies properly.

I've reached this point by researching independently so far, but I would really appreciate any advice or feedback I could get to see what exactly I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: I am also able to apply the translation successfully using the code below. Why does this work and not the one above?

```
auto translation {glm::translate(glm::mat4{1.0f}, glm::vec3{velocity.x, 0.f, velocity.z})};

object.model = translation * object.model;
```

Comment: What point do you want to rotate around? glm::rotate always rotates around the origin. Make sure the multiplication order of your transformations is correct.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, but when you translate you should consider where is the center/axis of the subsequent rotation e.g. choose properly the desired center of rotation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Right now I have it set so that whenever the mouse moves, the object and camera rotates to the direction of the mouse movement. The camera rotates around the center of the object, but the object rotates around itself?